# Send report to mail in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some product list with agent mail ID,
Daily basis I need to send report to the concern agents from Spreadsheet
[image]

Here is the report

```
    function myFunction() {
    {
    var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("responsing");
      var ws= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Request");
      var data = ws.getRange(1,1,1,ws.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  data.forEach(function(row){
      var htmlMessage=emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
      GmailApp.sendEmail(
        row[mail],
       "Report",
        "Your browser doesn't support HTML",
       {name:"VUC-GISOCC",htmlBody:htmlMessage,cc: 'agent' }
      );
    
      });
    
    }
```

I am using the above script, but don't know how to send content to the concern agent in cc.
Example

```
Agent user001@gmail.com should get Orange detail
Agent user002@gmail.com should get Apple detail
Agent user004@gmail.com should get Grape detail
```

FYI, I am using HTML body, that's why I added `htmlMessage`
It's getting only user001@gmail.com as I put 1 in `var data = ws.getRange(1,1,1,ws.getLastColumn()).getValues();`

Comment: Can you specifically show like a step-by-step example how you'd like to send the email? It is quite unclear since you're using mailApp.sendEmail inside a For Each loop (I suppose you'd like the message to be sent each agent emails) but you're saying you want to send content to the concern agent in CC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this `ws.getRange(1,1,1,ws.getLastColumn()).getValues();` to this `ws.getRange(2,1,ws.getLastRow()-1,ws.getLastColumn()).getValues();`

if you have other stuff below the table table then you may wish to use `ws.getRange(2,1,3,ws.getLastColumn()).getValues();` if you data doesn't change but if it does you will be forced to change the third parameter which is the number of rows in the range.

Comment: Hello Cooper,
But how it will send to the concern agent in cc??

Comment: I just want to know how to call Agent in loop in cc

Comment: Column 4 is row[3]